# Simplest way of hashing a password with multiple different hash algorithms

Tags: passwords, hash

I have a list of *plaintext* passwords that I would like to hash with various different hash algorithms (for educational purposes). As a minimum I would like to obtain hashes under MD5, SHA1, SHA256, (with and without salts), bcrypt, PBKDF2 and NTLM. Since [`hashcat`](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/) supports all of these, I thought the simplest approach would be to run `hashcat` on the passwords with all the different algorithms.

However, to my astonishment (and frustration), I haven't been able to find a simple way of doing this in `hashcat`! Since `hashcat` is targeted towards breaking already hashed passwords, it requires a list of hashes, not *plaintexts*.

Thus, is there a way of simply running each algorithm in `hashcat` on a password in the clear - to obtain its hashed value?

**Note:** I don't really care if it's `hashcat` I use or not, I'm only looking for a simple way to hash some passwords with various different hash algorithms - minimizing the amount scripting I have to do myself. So if you have a better tool or approach, please share it.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on [unix&linux stack exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), because it is about how to do something quickly in the command shell.

Comment: "for educational purposes" what did you expect to learn ?

Comment: @Phillip yes, I weren't sure where to put it either. Feel free to move it over to where you think it fits best.

Comment: @martialdidit it's not for me, but intended for some students to illustrate the difference in cracking speeds of some common approaches to storing passwords.

Comment: @hakoja Oh ! good idea, glad you teach by example to your students !

Answer (score 2):

On most UNIXoid operating systems, the `openssl` command line program should be available. It implements most of the hashes you mention. To use it just for hashing, pipe the output of `echo -n` to [`openssl dgst -[ALGORITHM]`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dgst.html). To calculate the SHA1 hashsum of "Hello World", for example, use this:

```
 echo -n "Hello World" | openssl dgst -sha1
```

openssl dgst supports the following algorithms: md5, md4, md2, sha1, sha, mdc2, ripemd160 .

Comment: OpenSSL has source for MD2 but it's excluded by default, you must custom build. It also has SHA-224,256,384,512 (but not the 180-4 "slash" variants) which I've seen used for pwhash, and Whirlpool which I haven't. The library has PBKDF2, but commandline can't access it directly. And you can add it on Windows with a Windows-friendly installer/uninstaller from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html .

Answer (score 1):

Python has a library called [passlib](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.html) that contains all of those algorithms.  Including NTLM which is broken into `nthash` and `lmhash`.  You could create an array of schemes:

`schemes = ["md5_crypt", ...]`

Then setup a crypt context with that list:

`pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["md5_crypt", "des_crypt"])`

Then loop through `len(schemes)` calling:

`hash = pwd_context.encrypt("passwordtohash", scheme=schemes[i])`

**Edit** 
It doesn't seem to be this simple.  I'm researching once I have a working script I will post it.

[Example of Usage](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.html) 
[Add Salt Using encrypt()](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/password_hash_api.html#passlib.ifc.PasswordHash.encrypt)
[Download PassLib](https://code.google.com/p/passlib/downloads/list)